# Arch Linux, Openbox and Desktop

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, desktop, openbox

I' m installing Arch with OpenBox, I' ve done everything but when I type

```
openbox-session
```

I have this error

```
Failed to open the display from the DISPLAY environment variable.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not the right way to initiate a x session with openbox,

Perhaps you meant to put that line in `~/.xinitrc`, and execute `startx` instead.

Remember that an X app can't be run outside the Xorg environment.

Comment: This covered in more detail at [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openbox#Openbox_as_a_stand-alone_WM).

Comment: Yes with startx is ok, but why in the wiki there is exec openbox-session ??

Comment: @AlessioMTX exec would replace the current shell process with the openbox-session process, thus X can know the exit status of it

Comment: @AlessioMTX Please read the whole section, it says "To run Openbox as a stand-alone window manager, **append the following to ~/.xinitrc**: exec openbox-session" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Wieland yes I wrote also in ~/.xinitrc: exec openbox-session

Comment: Just in case anyone doesn't realise (like me). You need to install `xinit` to run openbox. `sudo apt-get install xinit`.